# Proper model associations for a Rails quiz app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations

I'm working on a rails app for a quiz. I have three models for creating a quiz: quiz, question and choice. A quiz has questions, and questions have a number of choices, with 1 choice being correct.

The relationships are as follows:

```
Quiz 
belongs_to: course

Question
belongs_to: quiz
has_many: choices

Choice
belongs_to: question
```

I come from a background in C++ and the way I would structure this in C++ is to have a quiz class and a question class. I wouldn't make an entire class just for choices, because all they need to hold is a string (the choice) and whether it's the correct choice or not. My question is, should I even need to have a choice model?

Comment: Is this a multiple choice, choose one?

Comment: Is an examination a quiz? Or is it different?

Comment: Sorry, I restructured my question to make more sense.

Comment: Do `Question` and `Choice` have a many-to-many relationship? There's a `belongs_to` on both sides.

Comment: @Stefan that is why I thought to originally include a has many through relationship in my answer (I edited it out). What are your thoughts? The way it was explained with double `has_many` (instead of  double `belongs_to`) make me make the edit. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails associations can be tricky at first. Saying `belongs_to` means `is the child of`, just as `has_one` means `is the parent of one`. I would recommend a structure as follows:

```
Course
has_many :quizzes

Quiz 
belongs_to :course
has_many :questions

Question
belongs_to :quiz
has_many :choices

Choice
belongs_to :question
```

When you create an association, it means you are association two tables together through an `object_id` on the child association. Most tables (if not all) have an accompanying model. When you create your migrations (Ruby classes that help create the schema), be sure to properly include the associations and foreign keys necessary.

More on associations can be found here: [Rails Guides: Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

With these associations, however, you cannot reuse a choice for another question. By that, I mean you *can* create another choice object with the same string, but it will have a different `id`. To designate whether a choice is correct, you can have a `correct` attribute flag to either `true` or `false`. Since choices already have a `question_id`, you can be certain they will show up correctly on the exam results!

You can look up migrations here: [Rails Guides: Active Record Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

Comment: Why is it necessary to have has_many :choices, through: :questions?

Comment: Good question! I am rereading the documentation (first link), and the example used is doctor, patient, and appointment. I was over thinking your example. The `has many through`, I am seeing, should be used when two tables do not have foreign keys of each other, but share a common association. Since a question belongs to a quiz, it does not need the `through`. Sorry for the confusion! Going to edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a `Choice` model. But you need to correct the ***association*** in `Question` model

```
#Question
belongs_to :quiz
has_many :choices #as question will have many choices provided
belongs_to :examination
```